# how to make sure int is assigned a unique id for that thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I need to insert into database which has two columns-

```
ID      PrimaryKey String
ACCOUNT String
```

So that means each thread should be using unique id always and I need to store the same `ID` in `Account` column also. So suppose if `ID is 1` then in Database it should be stored as

```
ID  Account
1   SomeString+1
2   SomeString+2
3   SomeString+3
....
..

100 SomeString+100
```

I am concatenating that userID with that String always in Account column.

Below is my multithreaded code which will spawn multiple threads- And each thread will be getting a new unique ID everytime as I am using `AtomicInteger` for that. And it will insert that `ID` to `ID column` and also append that `ID` to `Account` column

But somehow in my below program what I have seen in that database is-

```
ID Account
1  String+2
2  String+1
3  String+3
```

Which is not right. It should be something like this-

```
ID Account
1  String+1
2  String+2
3  String+3
```

Below is the code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int noOfThreads = 4;
        final int noOfTasks = 10;

        final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(1);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTasks * noOfThreads; i++) {
            service.submit(new Task(id));
        }
    }


class Task implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicInteger id;
    private volatile int userId;

    public Task(AtomicInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();

        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(Constants.INSERT_ORACLE_SQL);

        userId = id.getAndIncrement();

        preparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(userId));
        preparedStatement.setString(2, Constants.getaAccount(userId));

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }  
}
```

And below is my `Constants class` which I have made immutable.

```
public final class Constants {

    public static String A_ACCOUNT;

    public final static String INSERT_ORACLE_SQL = "INSERT INTO XMP_TEST"
        + "("
        + "ID, A_ACCOUNT) VALUES"
        + "(?, ?)";



    public static String getaAccount(int userId) {      
        A_ACCOUNT = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"userId\":"+userId+"},\"cn\":1}]}";

        return A_ACCOUNT;
    }


}
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing here? I believe it's happening because of thread safety issue. Multiple threads modifying the `userID` integer I guess and that's why it is getting written wrongly to database.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the output isn't  "2 String+2" and then "1 String+1"?  That would happen because of race conditions.  What you are showing seems to be impossible since userId is not changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major problem I see is not with `Task.userId`, but rather with `Constants.A_ACCOUNT`: if two separate threads call `getaAccount` at the same time, then they'll both set `Constants.A_ACCOUNT` and both read it, so they can end up both having the same value, or each having the other's value, or whatnot. To fix this, you can use a local variable instead of a static field:

```
    public static String getaAccount(int userId) {      
        final String ret = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"userId\":"+userId+"},\"cn\":1}]}";

        return ret;
    }
```

or just dispense with the variable:

```
    public static String getaAccount(int userId) {      
        return "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"userId\":"+userId+"},\"cn\":1}]}";
    }
```

(You say that you've made `Constants` immutable, but that's not really true. *Instances* of `Constants` will be immutable, because they have no fields at all; but `Constants` itself has a publically modifiable field, so it's *very* mutable!)

More generally, you shouldn't be using fields for temporary values only needed within a specific method, and only during a single call to it. Even when it's not a synchronization problem, it's a maintenance problem. For example, `Task` does not need a `volatile int userId`; `userId` should just be a local variable inside its `run` method.

Also, I'd recommend wrapping your `AtomicInteger` in its own class, `IncrementingCounter` or something, that offers just one method, called (say) `getNewId`. Then `getNewId` will be the only class that has to deal with coordination between threads. All other classes can be made threadsafe by regular techniques (immutability, only existing within a single thread, etc.).

Comment: aaahh... How can I do that. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading and modifying a static variable without any kind of synchronization from multiple threads: `A_ACCOUNT`. Just make it a local variable in `getaacount()` and everything should work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

considering that the digits of a number is also a string, this problem was solved many years ago:

- Add an auto-increment column to your parent table
- Now inserting a parent record will give you a unique number
- You don't say which database you're using, but every DB has a way of retrieving the value of the auto increment just inserted, so retrieve that and use it as your unique value.

If you can't change the data type if your key, also copy the auto increment value into your string column. It doesn't matter that it's numerical - it's still unique.

Comment: Re: "You don't say which database you're using": True, but it's obviously Oracle. Or at least, I *really* hope so. (So, (s)he would use a sequence rather than an auto-incrementing column. But, same idea. +1)